# I'm trying to add values into database, but every time I try to add some thing i get an error 'Connection must be valid and open.'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

This is the error I'm getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwDka.png)

with this code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtID.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtMobileNo.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter all of your detail.", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    else
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO tablemm (id,Name,MobileNo) VALUES ('" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "')";

        OpenConnection();

        MySqlCommand ObjCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, ObjConnection);
        ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Alert!

Comment: post the full code! ObjConnection and OpenConnection() method code

Comment: Also don't link pictures, it makes us click and we hate clicking

Comment: //Global variable
        private MySqlConnection ObjConnection;
        private string server, database, uid, password;

        //intialize connection
        private void InitializeConnection()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "table";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            ObjConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        }

Comment: private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            
            try
            {
                ObjConnection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Can not connect to server");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User name/Password");
                        break; }
                return false;
            }  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to call `Open`

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(myExecuteQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.Connection.Open();  // wallah 
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

Also use a `using` statement where possible,

**Disclaimer**: This is only for demonstration purposes and I can't be held responsible for the people you maim and otherwise hurt with this code

Comment: How do you know, he/she hasn't called `Open` in the `OpenConnection();` method?

Comment: yeah he was right actually ,but now another problem Popup

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'The host localhost does not support SSL connections.'

Comment: @imzia99 this is basically another question though this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086283/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-the-host-localhost-does-not-support-ssl

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your `INSERT` statement should be *after* you open your connection with the database and right before you close it.

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: yes it is after the Open Connection ,it is in the  end actually