# "The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have Added SslMode='none' part to the data source in the connection string since there was a MySQL exception called,

> “The host localhost does not support SSL connections.”

I referred this solution in StackOverflow.
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108611/9589180)

After that, the error was gone. But when I tried to Debug using step into in the 2nd iteration of the program there was an error,

The error triggers in bl.Load(); in the below code

```
library.WriteErrorLog("Update The Table");
                            MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                            comm.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE jobs";
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                            library.WriteErrorLog("truncate Table");
                            bl.Load();
```

> "The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version"

[image]

The connection string is as follows:

```
string connStr = "data source=localhost; UID='13user';database='13shop';port=3306;password='123';SslMode='none'";
```

Any clue about this error?

Comment: Edit your question and show the statement causing the error, and the full text of the error.

Comment: Read https://mariadb.org/state-ssl-mariadb/ . They no longer support SSL for a long time. Try the add cert method in the links, see if it works.

Comment: Hey @Sloan Thrasher I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `bl` belongs to? The message is very confusing without providing any stack trace, since command execution happens in MariaDB side.

Comment: Do you think with the error message the mariadb version might be relevant? Does the `jobs` table actually exist?

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using? Please paste the _full_ exception message and call stack _as text_ as per http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/.