# The host localhost does not support SSL connections

Tags: mysql, ssl, toad

I want to connect my Mysql5.6 to Toad for Mysql IDE version 7.3.1, When i am trying to connect using connection TCP, i am getting the following error.

[image: The screenshot shows the error....]

The error clearly says it does not support SSL connection. But i am trying to connect the connection type is TCP, i do know why its asking for SSL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: “The host localhost does not support SSL connections.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086283/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-the-host-localhost-does-not-support-ssl)